# Flask shell - how to set server name for url_for _external=True?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a flask app running in a docker container. All works fine, except when I want to do some manual jobs in the same docker container from flask shell. The problem is that the `url_for(x, _external=True)` always returns https://localhost, doesn't matter how I try to set the server name in the shell.
I have obviously tried setting the SERVER_NAME to no change.

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from flask import current_app
>>> current_app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'example.com'
>>> from app import models
>>> models.Registration.send_registration(id=123)
```

The jinja template is having:
`{{ url_for('main.index', _external=True, _scheme='https') }`}

Which generates:
https://localhost

I would like to get:
https://example.com

I am using Flask 0.11, Werkzeug 0.11.10 and Jinja2 2.8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your app uses the `SERVER_NAME` defined when the application context was created.

If you want to do it in a shell, you can create a test request context after you set the `SERVER_NAME`.

```
>>> from flask import current_app, url_for
>>> current_app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'example.com'
>>> with current_app.test_request_context():
...     url = url_for('index', _external=True)
...
>>> print url
http://example.com/
```

We can dig in Flask code to understand it.

Flask `url_for` uses the [`appctx.url_adapter`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/7c271401b284e6fcc2040fffe317342e2a17a902/flask/helpers.py#L296) to build this URL. This `url_adapter` is defined when the [`AppContext`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/8d7e7aab31f0e3cf4d009376b6d210ae1a27785b/flask/ctx.py#L167) is initialized, and it happens when the shell is started. It calls the [`app.create_url_adapter`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/21d595bee73e65a28201709bd1a8b97c42aff5d2/flask/app.py#L1774) and it uses the defined `SERVER_NAME`.

Comment: Thanks, that has worked. I didn't realize that I need to create a new request context after setting the SERVER_NAME. Thanks again!

Comment: are there any flaws when using test_request_context()? I'm worried this is not an applicable solution for production servers. Please help!

Comment: @TheWhiteLlama I know this is late, but if a new context is all that's needed, then you could try using `with current_app.app_context(): ...`

Answer (score 2):

This solution is very similar to the one presented already, except it requires less steps:

```py
from flask import current_app, url_for

with current_app.test_request_context('localhost.com'):
    url = url_for('index')
    ...
```

This way there is no need to set up the config `SERVER_NAME` since we are injecting a `reqctx` on the spot so that `url_for` can properly build the path. For my case I want a relative path so I don't need to add attribute `_external`.