# Email with url_for _external=True, sent from docker container send localhost in return link. Need host subdomain

Tags: docker, nginx, flask

I have a flask web-app in docker containers with an nginx reverse proxy.  Each container is a subdomain so 123.someurl.com & abc.someurl.com.  The users register to use the app, when they submit their name and email, i send them an email with a link to set their password with a token.  Everything works great except the link that gets sent is localhost:5000/reset_password/token.

I need the link to be 123.someurl.com/reset_password/token or abc.someurl.com/reset_password/token depending on which container they are part of.

This is my function where it pulls the url for the return address.

```
def send_welcome_email(user):
    token = user.get_reset_token(expires_sec=86400)
    msg = Message('Welcome to someurl.com',
              recipients=[user.email])
    msg.body = f'''You have been registered with someurl.com, you must reset your password before you can login. To do so visit the following link:

    {url_for('users.reset_token', token=token, _external=True)}

    mail.send(msg)
```

First I moved the msg.body to a template to see if that would help.  Then I tried adding SERVER_NAME and .test_request_context, which solved the _external url_for but it also messed up the non-external url_for's.  My updated function.

```
def send_welcome_email(user):
    token = user.get_reset_token(expires_sec=86400)
    msg = Message(
        'Welcome to someurl.com',
        recipients=[user.email]
    )
    current_app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'development.someurl.com'
    with current_app.test_request_context():
        url = url_for(
            'users.reset_token',
            _external=True,
            token=token
        )
    msg.html = render_template(
        'users/register_email.html',
        url=url,
        username=user.username
    )
    mail.send(msg)
```

The site works fine at startup but as soon as i register a user, the site cannot find any of the url's.

Comment: Have you tried setting `SERVER_NAME`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631886/flask-shell-how-to-set-server-name-for-url-for-external-true

Comment: I had to edit my answer because when i added the solution from (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37658053/6814989) it solved my "url_for _external" link problem, but it then made all my regular "url_for" links not work so well.